# How to run nodejs server in the background when packaged as windows .exe using zeit?

Tags: node.js, zeit-pkg

We have nodejs server, packaged as exe using zeit packager. When user double clicks the exe, server gets started, but it keeps the command window open. We wish to start the server in the background. Only action we can expect from the end user is to double click the exe.

Is there a way to run this exe / nodejs server in the background?

**Update**:
Following is the flow we are trying to implement:

- User runs the exe file
- Node application gets trigger without any command line argument
- As there's no argument, the node application triggers VBScript
- VBScript calls the same exe file in hidden mode with argument = serverStart
- Node application starts the server as it receives argument = serverStart

But we are getting error = Cannot find module 'serverStart'
Following is our code in VBS

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
objShell.Run """" & "path-to-exe" & """serverStart""", 1, False
```

Please note that, if we directly execute VBS file, it works fine. Only when packaged in exe and run, it gives the error.

Comment: Did you look at the suggestion here ?
https://github.com/zeit/pkg/issues/520

Comment: @VenkatReddy I updated my answer as per your comment

Comment: Please up vote if it solved your question

Comment: Thanks Venkat but Its not working. I have specified the error we are getting.